# SSRS Find the closest date/time

Tags: reporting-services

I have the following issue:
The Case will be calculated using the latest Calculation File. The Case and Calculation File are from two different Datasets without any key elements.

Dataset 1:

Dataset 2:

[image]

I wanted to get something like the following:

[image]

For Case created on 12 Jan and 27 Jan, they used the Calculation File uploaded on 12 Jan. Then a new file was uploaded 28 Jan. A new case created on 29 Jan used this latest calculation file.

Now, I have the expression to generate the **Used Calculation File**:

I added Row number to Dataset 2. To get the **Used Calculation File**, I have

> =iif(LookUp(1, Fields!Row.Value, Fields!File_Upload_Time.Value, "Dataset 2")<(Fields!Case_Created_Time.Value, "Dataset 1"), LookUp(1, Fields!Row.Value, Fields!Completed.Value, "CoreJob"),                                       iif(LookUp(2, Fields!Row.Value, Fields!Completed.Value, "CoreJob")< (Fields!Case_Created_Time.Value, "Dataset 1"),  LookUp(2, Fields!Row.Value, Fields!Completed.Value, "CoreJob"),                                                              iif(LookUp(3, Fields!Row.Value, Fields!Completed.Value, "CoreJob")<(Fields!Case_Created_Time.Value, "Dataset 1"), LookUp(3, Fields!Row.Value, Fields!Completed.Value, "CoreJob"),                                                                 iif(LookUp(4, Fields!Row.Value, Fields!Completed.Value, "CoreJob")< (Fields!Case_Created_Time.Value, "Dataset 1"), LookUp(4, Fields!Row.Value, Fields!Completed.Value, "CoreJob"),0))))

It does the job for now, but there will be many rows in Dataset 2, I can not use the above to lookup for row N.  Is there anything effective to do the job?

Basically, the idea is for each Case, Filter the Used calculation File by: earlier than the Case Created Time, Then, select the latest **Used Calculation Value**

Please ask for further clarification if i have failed to explain something properly. Thanks.

Comment: Is combining the datasets in SQL an option?

Comment: Dataset 1 contains the first two columns (Case ID and Created Time) of the final dataset.

Comment: @stubker thank you :) but there is not relationship between dataset 1 and 2, i.e. no primary key element to connect them.... Wanted to know how to do a loop to find the closest from dataset 2, rather than using limited multi iif functions...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend altering your dataset (if possible) rather than attempting this type of comparison on the report itself; you can use the [`APPLY` operator](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) like:

```
SELECT ct.CaseId, ct.CreatedTime, CalcFile.UsedCalcValue
FROM CaseTable AS ct 
    CROSS APPLY(SELECT TOP 1 cft.UsedCalcValue
                FROM CalcFileTable AS cft
                WHERE ct.CreatedTime >= cft.UsedCalcValue
                ORDER BY cft.UsedCalcValue DESC) AS CalcFile
```

Comment: Thank you. It looks like a great solution. I will try it out. :)

Comment: Thank you sooooooo much for your time and help. I've tried CROSS APPLY function, it works brilliant ! :)